# Embedding JavaScript in ASPNET1.1 C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net-1.1

I have a web application that requires scripting capabilities to be able to run business logic without need to recompile the application.

So my idea is to use a Javascript engine and load the script from files or database and run an entity by the BL in order to validate things, do logic, etc.

Ive been searching for many questions here and I couldnt find one that works for NET1.1.

Anyone knows one that I can use?

I found JINT which seems great but is NET2.0+.

Another option I had was using Boo (I added a question here to know its speed as an interpreter only), but the developers already know JS so it will be more familiar and faster for them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found LuaInterface 1.3.0 which is the last version that supports NET1.1 (LuaInterface is already in 2.x) that runs on Lua5.0.

So I'm going with it.

I would've loved to do Javascript, but is not possible to make it run in NET1.1 and my app just will not be upgraded in the near future to NET2.0.